# Find whether element in list integer?

Tags: scheme

I was wondering, how do you check if every element in a list is an integer or not? I can check the first element by using (integer? (car list), but if I do (integer? (cdr list), it always returns false (#f) because the whole of the last part of the list is not an integer as a group. 
In this case let's say list is defined as.
(define list '(1 2 5 4 5 3))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  (define get-integers
    (lambda (x)
     (if (null? x)
        "All elements of list are integers"
        (if (integer? (car x))
            (get-integers (cdr x))
            "Not all elements are an integer"))))
```

Comment: Returning strings instead of booleans? using nested `if`s instead of `cond`? This solution is not very idiomatic.

Comment: It's better for clarity as this is for showing the logic behind this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Practical Schemes provide functions for doing tests across whole sequences.  An application of the [*andmap*](http://practical-scheme.net/wiliki/schemexref.cgi?andmap) function, for example, would be appropriate.  Racket provides a [*for/and*](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html#%28part._for_and_and_for_or%29) to do something similar.  If you really needed to write out the loop by hand, you'll be using recursion.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is test each element in the list to see if it satisfies a condition (being an integer, in this case). When you evaluate `(integer? (car list))` on a list of integers, you're checking if the first element in the list is an integer, and that's fine. But the expression `(integer? (cdr list))`  tests if a *list* is an integer (because `cdr` returns a list), and that won't work - you need to test the *next* element in the list, and the next, and so on until the list is empty.

There are several ways to do the above, the most straightforward would be to recur on the list testing each element in turn, returning `false` if a non-integer element was found or `true` if all the list was consumed without finding a non-integer element, like this:

```
(define (all-integers? lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) #t)
        ((not (integer? (car lst))) #f)
        (else (all-integers? (cdr lst)))))
```

A more practical approach would be to use a built-in procedure, like this:

```
(andmap integer? lst)
```

[`andmap`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html) will check if all the elements in `lst` evaluate to `true` for the given predicate. For example:

```
(andmap integer? '(1 2 3))
> #t

(andmap integer? '(1 "x" 3))
> #f
```

Answer (score 1):

SRFI-1 uses the terms `every` and `any` rather than `andmap` and `ormap`. `match` can also be used:

```
(define list-of-integers?
  (lambda (lst)
    (match lst
           (((? number?) ..1) #t)
           (_ #f))))
```